# How do I know which widget fired an event (GWT)

Tags: events, gwt, widget, datepicker

I have modified the `onValueChange` method of the class `ValueChangeHandler`, so that I can use it in all the `DatePicker` that I have in my application, but I would like to know which `DatePicker` fired the event. How do I get that information?

here is the code of my `ValueChangeHandler` custom class:

```
class calendarChangeHandler implements ValueChangeHandler<Date>{

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
        endCalendar.hideDatePicker();
        initCalendar.hideDatePicker();
        Date initDate = initCalendar.getValue();
        Date endDate = endCalendar.getValue();
        int numDias = 0;
        if (initDate != null &&  endDate != null && (endDate.after(initDate))){
                numDias = (int)((endDate.getTime()-initDate.getTime())/MILLSECS_PER_DAY);
                createTable(numDias+2);
            }
    }

}
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a few widgets attached to the handler, it's probably easier to use an `if` statement:

```java
ValueChangeHandler<Date> handler = new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
        if (box1.equals(event.getSource())) {
            //It was box1.
        } else {
            //It was box2.
        }
    }
};
```

Otherwise, just use `event.getSource()` and cast the result to the desired type:

```java
ValueChangeHandler<Date> handler = new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
        DateBox srouce = (DateBox) event.getSource();
        //Do something with the source.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The getSource() method of [ValueChangeEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.html) should give you who fired the event.

Comment: But when I try to show it like this:  
Window.alert(String.valueOf(event.getSource()));  
I just get the type of the Objet in this message:  
<input class="gwt-DateBox" type="text">

Comment: Try to cast it to a DateBox.